# What functionality will I lose by installing CM on my Xperia Z3?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z3

I am considering to replace the stock rom of my Xperia Z3 with Cyanogenmod.

What are the functions that will no longer be accessible / installable after doing this switch?

For example I heard that Z3 comes with special DRM protected drivers for the camera, so I assume the camera will be worse after installing CM.

What about the Stamina mode to save battery? Will I still be able to use this somehow?

And what about the PlayStation functionalities of the phone?

Comment: Yes your camera may perform worse in low light. You will lose your playstation certificate. The stamina mode is associated with the stock rom of Xperia so you will lose your Stamina mode too

Comment: Damn, thank you. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: From my experience, you will lose all the above, and often things like WiFi, bluetooth, a working screen, 3g, lte etc. It depends on if it is a stable version of CM or a nightly. The nightly ones have a lot of known bugs and are NOT a daily driver. Anything 'Sony' on your device will be gone for sure.

Comment: But there may be way where you can backup the TA partition and restore it. So that your DRM keys are intact

Answer (score 3):

in my experience the phone worked really well except for the camera. To take photos I used Google stock camera, shots usually came out distorted (HDR unusable) and except when in perfect light conditions photos where bad, also audio recording of any kind (voice or video) was impossible to achieve. So finally I went back to Sony ROM ... but feels outdated and slow in comparison